# Tensor product is unique up to unique isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $M,N$ be two $A$-modules. I have heard it said that then the tensor product $M\otimes_A N$ is unique up to unique isomorphism. This confuses me so I would like to check if I understand this correctly.

I know that if $(T,g)$ and $(T',g')$ both satisfy the universal property of of the tensor product then there is a a unique isomphism $j:T\rightarrow T'$ such that $g'=j\circ g$. I would to check that this does not imply that we if have $(T,g)$,$(T',g'$) and $(T'',g'')$ then we must have $(T,g)=(T'',g'')$?

For any ring $R$, $R$ is an $R$-module and $R\otimes_R R=R$. Now multiplication from $\mu:R\times R\rightarrow R $ is a bilinear map. So $(R,\mu)$ is certainly one such tensor product. Suppose $\phi,\psi:R\rightarrow R$ are two automorphisms of $R$. Then $(R,\mu)$,$(R,\phi\circ \mu)$ and $(R,\psi\circ \mu)$ are three tensor products but non are pairwise equally.

Comment: Is $(T'',g'')$ another module with the universal property? If so, then $(T,g)$ and $(T'',g'')$ are _also_ uniquely isomorphic.

Comment: I understand that pairwise they must be isomorphism and this isomorphism must be unique. But If we have three such modules obeying the universal property, must one of the isomorphism be the identity?

Comment: Aaaaah, I understand now. No. For a silly example, you can do set theoretic trickery: Fix one tensor product $(T,g)$. Now for every number $n$, look at the set $\{ (t,n) ~|~ t \in T\}$ with the algebraic structure the same as in $T$ (we just ignore the $n$ we're carrying around). Then this gives countably many isomorphic structures, all satisfying the universal property, but none of these isomorphisms are the identity

Comment: If you'd like to post this comment as an answer I can accept it to close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

No. In fact, you can have *lots* of nonisomorphic objects, no two of which are equal.

For a silly example, you can do some set theoretic trickery:

Fix one tensor product $(T,g)$. Now, for each natural $n$, look at the set $\{(t,n) ~|~ t \in T \}$ with the same algebraic structure as $T$ (we just ignore the $n$ we're carrying around).

This gives countably many isomorphic structures, all satisfying the universal property, but none of these isomorphisms are the identity.

---

I hope this helps ^_^